# How to prepopulated from data using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, perl

I have added an aweber form on my project file called adduser.php. It has three fields First name, Last Name and Email. When user will submit form data they will go to welcome.php page. In welcome.php page I have some welcome message and and button called "Start". When a user click on "Start" Button they will get a custom form.

So, My question is now, How can i show previously data that was submited by user on adduser.php on my custom form.

Remember that I did not use any custom database to store adduser.php form data. This page handled by aweber.com embedded Perl script.

There are total four pages on my Project folder. one is adduser.php and then welcom.php, then custom.from.php and last one is thankyou.php.
            This is the form script for adduser.php. It is a embedded from script provided by aweber.com.

```
<form method="post" class="af-form-wrapper" action="https://www.aweber.com/scripts/addlead.pl"  >
    <div style="display: none;">
        <input type="hidden" name="meta_web_form_id" value="1305186106" />
        <input type="hidden" name="meta_split_id" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="listname" value="awlist3791609" />
        <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://localhost/php/intro.php?" id="redirect_33699466c49909887d43ec924c761a52" />
        <input type="hidden" name="meta_adtracking" value="My_Web_Form" />
        <input type="hidden" name="meta_message" value="1" />
        <input type="hidden" name="meta_required" value="name (awf_first),name (awf_last),email" />
        <input type="hidden" name="meta_tooltip" value="" />
    </div>
    <div id="af-form-1305186106" class="af-form">
        <div id="af-header-1305186106" class="af-header">
            <div class="bodyText">
                <p> </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="af-body-1305186106"  class="af-body af-standards">
            <div class="af-element">
                <label class="previewLabel" for="awf_field-71044792-first">First Name:</label>
                <div class="af-textWrap">
                    <input id="awf_field-71044792-first" type="text" class="text" name="name (awf_first)" value=""/>
                </div>
                <div class="af-clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="af-element">
                <label class="previewLabel" for="awf_field-71044792-last">Last Name:</label>
                <div class="af-textWrap">
                    <input id="awf_field-71044792-last" class="text" type="text" name="name (awf_last)" value=""/>
                </div>
                <div class="af-clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="af-element">
                <label class="previewLabel" for="awf_field-71044793">Email: </label>
                <div class="af-textWrap">
                    <input class="text" id="awf_field-71044793" type="text" name="email" value=""/>
                </div>
                <div class="af-clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="af-element buttonContainer">
                <input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Start Screening"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I'm in big trouble, I'm unable to handle I'm waiting for support from expert developer. I'm still working on local server connected with internet.

Comment: Please post the code

Comment: try to include at the top of your new php file require_once '/pathtofile/adduser.php' i think your variable should be global for this to work

Comment: I hove posted my adduser.php code. Please take a look! I did not use any variable to handle this prom as it is handled by predefined awever script.

Comment: you don't have any php! adduser.php is all html and a perl script is handling everything addlead.pl

Comment: I'm not worried about perl script handlaer. I have just sow the from script and i have added this from on my adduser.php page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$_SESSION` to use your variables through your entire application runtime. At the end, just close them to clear your users browsers.

It's a common practice used by "flash session messages". They setup the message by `$_SESSION` and close when the variables has no use anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Change the default action of your form

```
<form method="post" class="af-form-wrapper" action="https://www.aweber.com/scripts/addlead.pl"  >
```

to

```
   <form method="post" class="af-form-wrapper" action="trial.php"  >
```

In this file trial.php, start the seeion first and then use the session variables as follows

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["first-title"] = $_POST['awf-first'];
```

and so on for each of the form inputs and then redirect the page to default action using location

```
header('Location : Aweber perl script link');
```

Comment: I used like this <?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$_SESSION = $_POST['awf-first'];
$_SESSION = $_POST['awf-last'];
$_SESSION = $_POST['email'];
header('Location : https://www.aweber.com/scripts/addlead.pl');
} but not working

Comment: You do not have anything that will set the submit variable. So remove the first "if" condition. I had a small issue with the code I had written because I hadn't provided a name to the session variables. See the edit now. If you feel that there is still problem, remove the header line at the end of this file and echo the variables to see them after the form is submitted.